# How to communicate between iOS and OS X

Tags: ios, macos, swift2, osx-yosemite, ios9

I'm trying to make an app to allow me to switch from playing music on my computer over to my phone and back. I have it largely implemented, but I have reached a snag. Namely, how to tell the other device that it should start the transition.
How should I go about communicating between these devices? (iOS 9 iPhone and OS X 10.10 Macbook)
I thought about Bluetooth and the Multipeer Connectivity framework, but I'm not sure they really fit what I'm trying to do. I need to be able to send some information back and forth about what song to start playing and when to begin the transition.

Any help on the best way to go about this is welcome

Thanks,
-tlf

P.S. I'm using Swift, so any examples in that would be especially appreciated.

Comment: You can use core bluetooth, or if they are on the same WiFi network then you could use Bonjour and TCP/IP

Comment: This should be done by nsuseractivity if you don't want to go against framework. BTW you still face issue - once the app goes to background there is no update and no way to stop it on iphone